# The sentence doesn't seem to make sense in the context of a foreword of the book "Third Girl" by Agatha Christie

Tags: meaning, sentence

In the foreword of the book "Third Girl" by Agatha Christie, I read the following sentence:

> Millions of readers from every age and country are addicts to the work of this most absorbing and distinguished of story-teller. **Not one of those addicts will care to miss this brilliant new story**, in which Hercule Poirot plays a full an dazzling role ...

What I don't understand is the highlighted part. Does it mean that no one will care about this new story? But it is a bit weird to say so in the foreword of a book, isn't it? Or does it mean the opposite?

Comment: In the given context, *care* means *wish*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

By way of putting the comment from michael.hor257k (above) into the formal regalia of an English Language & Usage answer, I offer the relevant entry for *care* as a transitive verb from *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **care** ... *vt* **1 :** to be concerned about or to the extent of {don't *care* what they say} {doesn't *care* a damn} **2 :** WISH {if you *care* to go}

As used in the foreword to *Third Girl*, the verb *care* is transitive and has the meaning given in the second definition above. The sense of the sentence is "If you love Christie's writing, you won't want to deprive yourself of the pleasure of reading this book."